# ' & " inside a php regexp

Tags: php, regex

Would this be the correct regexp to allow `A-Z a-z 0-9` and symbols `#&()-\;,.'"` and spaces?

I'm struggling with the `'` and `"` inside the regexp. Is what I've done correct? Note the `\'` and `\"`. It just doesn't seem right. Whats the right way to do it?

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9#&()-\;,.\'\" ]+$/i', $username) )   
{   
    echo "Good";   
}   
else   
{   
    echo "Bad";   
}
```

Comment: the dash `-` should be at the beginning or the end of the regexp to avoid being interpreted as a range.

Comment: The dash doesn't need to be escaped if it's the last character in a character class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash should be escaped, and the double quote does not need to be. Bizarrely, you need to **quadruple** escape the backslash before the semi-colon. Otherwise it is interpreted as if you are escaping the semi-colon and is ignored.*

```
'/^[a-z0-9#&()\-\\\\;,.\'" ]+$/i'
```

You can also put an unescaped dash at the beginning of a character class, though that's a bit obscure and may momentarily confuse someone unaware of that option. It works because a dash at the start cannot be part of a valid character range, so it can only be a literal dash character.

```
'/^[-a-z0-9#&()\\\\;,.\'" ]+$/i'
```

<sup>* The `\\\\;` is reduced to `\\;` by PHP before the regex engine sees it. The regex engine then reduces `\\;` to `\;`. Thus, four backslashes! A single backslash `\;` becomes simply `;`. The same goes for `\\;`—PHP reduces that to `\;` and then the regex engine interprets `\;` as a plain semi-colon `;`. No less than four will do.<sup>†</sup></sup>

<sup>† Actually, I lied. You can get away with three backslashes. But then you're abusing the leniency of PHP's parser a bit. Four is definitely best.</sup>

Comment: I kept getting : Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'. So i did '/^[a-z0-9#&()\-\\\\;,.\'" ]+$/i' Note the / at the beginning. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I lost your starting slash when I copy-and-pasted.

Comment: The semicolon does not need to be escaped at all.

Comment: @Gumbo I agree. The OP is trying to match a literal backslash, and happened to place it before the semi-colon in his regex.

Comment: Before I go :), the right way to allow new lines (the enter key) in the regexp above would be like this, right? '/^[a-z0-9#&()\-\\\\;,.\'"\r\n ]+$/i' I added \r\n. No harm if done this way?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can also use `\s` as a shorthand for all whitespace if tabs are okay too.

Answer (score -1):

Brackets also needed to be escaped

```
'/^[a-z0-9#&\(\)\-;,.\'" ]+$/i'
```

Comment: Incorrect.  Parentheses are not special inside character classes.

Comment: This answer too gives me the error : preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in...